# Can i use attribute of the same name and of the same value in XML?

Tags: xml, attributes

Can i use attribute of the same name and of the same value? I mean I just want each to have identifier. Should I use id attribute perhaps? And one thing, can i name an attribute or there are already reserved words for attributes. sorry for this noob question. I am just a beginner. I always see element vs. attribute but doesn't answer this question.

```
<character-reference>
        <reference category="reference">
            <name>Jane Doe</name>
            <company>Google, Inc.</company>
            <position>Senior Web Developer</position>
            <contact>09524652565</contact>
        </reference>
        <reference category="reference">
            <name>John Doe</name>
            <company>Google, Inc.</company>
            <position>Data Analyst</position>
            <contact>09468975846</contact>
        </reference>
    </character-reference>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XML you it's not allowed to use attributes with the same name for the same element:

```
<!-- This is invalid -->
<reference category="reference1" category="reference2"/>
```

Attributes with different names for same element are allowed:

```
<!-- This is valid -->
<reference category1="reference" category2="reference"/>
```

There are no reserved words in XML, but XML structure may be defined by a [DTD](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd_intro.asp) or [XSD](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_intro.asp).

Your XML file is syntactically correct. For future references you could take a look at [w3schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp).

Comment: Is my code correct, since I used "category" attribute on different element, but I also gave them the same value? Or would that cause me a problem?

Comment: Yes, your code is correct. Attributes "category" may have same or different values. The main restriction is not to have several attributes with same name in same element.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to give each element a unique identifier, then I think with a new XML design I would probably use an `xml:id` attribute:

```
    <reference category="reference" xml:id="P123456">
        <name>Jane Doe</name>
        <company>Google, Inc.</company>
        <position>Senior Web Developer</position>
        <contact>09524652565</contact>
    </reference>
```

There are other ways of ensuring attributes are unique, but they typically involve an external schema or DTD, so `xml:id` is simpler. This is a magic name and if you want to achieve the same effect with an attribute name of your own choosing then it needs a schema or DTD.